# Database setup for Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-community

I'm new to the Visual Studio world and currently working on a project that I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to connect to a MySql database. I have added the NuGet package MySql.Data, but any direction on where to go from there would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this date Visual Studio for mac does not have the capability to connect to a MySql database. Hopefully this will be included soon.